# How not to reload an excel Addin

Tags: excel, vba

I have built an Excel Macro (as an Excel Addin) to randomly generate numbers.
I built it because the rand() function on excel keep generating new numbers at each action in the Excel file. So I tried to build something that "freeze" the formula once it has generated a number.
It works pretty well but when I close the file and reopen it, the numbers change.

How can I fix that ?
I have tried something like : If current cell = Blank ==> generate, otherwise exit function. But it doesn't work.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
 Function RandomFreeze()

Static AlreadyRandomized As Boolean

AlreadyRandomized = False
Static Low As Double
Static High As Double
Low = 1
High = 100000000

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "" Then

    If AlreadyRandomized = False Then
    RandomFreeze = Int(Rnd * (High + 1 - Low)) + Low
    AlreadyRandomized = True
    End If

Else
MsgBox "Erreur"
AlreadyRandomized = True
End If



End Function
```

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't be able to do this from a UDF I'm afraid. Better to use a normal macro that populates the right cells with the random numbers somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of `AlreadyRandomized` variable to a [CustomDocumentProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-customdocumentproperties-property-excel) and read/set its value accordingly.

```
Public Sub T()

    Dim p As Object
    Set p = CustomPropertyByName("AlreadyRandomized")

    If Not CBool(p.Value) Then 'Randomize

    p.Value = True 'Randomized
End Sub
```

Two helper functions, one creates the property if it doesn't exist and returns a reference to it and the second simply checks if the property exists.

```
'CustomPropertyByName()
Public Function CustomPropertyByName(ByVal propertyName As String) As Object
    If Not PropertyExists(propertyName) Then
        ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:=propertyName, _
                                                  LinkToContent:=False, _
                                                  Type:=msoPropertyTypeNumber, _
                                                  Value:=0
    End If
    Set CustomPropertyByName = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(propertyName)
End Function
```

```
'PropertyExists()
Private Function PropertyExists(ByVal propertyName As String) As Boolean
    Dim p As Object
    For Each p In ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties
       If p.Name = propertyName Then
           PropertyExists = True
           Exit Function
       End If
    Next p
End Function
```

Note: A runtime error occurs if you try to access a `CustomDocumentProperty` that doesn't exist.